# Newly created azure subscription not available in portal

Tags: azure

I have an old (+2 years) Azure account that I used in the past for testing purposes.

Today I sign-up again and created a **new** subscription of type "Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Professional", and canceled the existing subscription.

Now, in the Portal, the new subscription is **not available** in the respective drop-down, when I try to create any service.

Instead, the only available subscription in the drop-down is the canceled one (which is not selectable).

I was expecting that a new subscription should be available in the Portal immediatelly. Is it normal to take some hours?

Comment: My Azure subscriptions shows two entries: "Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Professional" and a "Visual Studio Professional with MSDN".  Once Azure works out their issues, I may actually use them for some smaller projects.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have a **second** account and the new subscription is visible on that second acount!

Both accounts are linked somehow and I was not aware.